react-native-compressor Video quality
What are the best configurations to make videos preserve the same resolution and quality, while still saving space. I am putting quality over space, since storage is relativly cheap, and user experience is a high priority.
result = await VideoCompression.compress(
            media.path,
            {
              compressionMethod: 'manual',
              bitrate: 8000000, 
              resolution: '1080p', 
              frameRate: 30,
              keyframeInterval: 30, 
              codec: 'H265',
            },
            progress => {
              console.log('Compression Progress: ', progress);
            },
          );

